# TSVN - pending changes from current solution instead of all checkout folder

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Visual Studio 2019
TSVN 4.8.53
(tried also with VisualSVN 7.2.0  )
TortoiseSVN installed with command line tools

I want to see in Pending changes from TSVN only the changes for current solution. Instead I see all the changes from the entire checkout folder.
In Options => Windows= > Options, at "working copy root path" it is put the path of the checkout folder.

I remembered I used this extension successfully with VS2017

Do you any idea what could be?

UPDATED (26.11.2019)

It seems I cannot make TSVN or VisualSVN to work in an elegant way. I can set the working copy on each project to point to my solution folder, but:
1. I have more than 300 projects.
2. It modifies the source files

I tried to contact the support from both extension but still no answer

Answer (score 0):

you can find the setting in Extensions>VisualSVN>Set working copy root. Uncheck "determine working copy automatically":

[image: setting]